# Exclude some parameters with POST request on RestKit

Tags: objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I've just integrated RestKit with a Mac application for communicating with a web service. After much confusion, I have successfully got requests and responses working using it.

The problem I am now finding is that when I want to make a POST request.

I have created a RKRequestDescriptor with a mapping for a whole number of properties and all of the properties are being sent as parameters for the query. I want a way of dynamically changing the parameters that are sent, for example not sending some parameters where the property is nil.

Is this possible as part of the built-in functionality of RestKit? And if so, how?

Comment: Only to not send nil parameters? Or some specific exclusion logic? The answer from @GoodSp33d covers the specific exclusion.

Comment: At the moment just excluding nil parameters but possibly more complex stuff later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use RestKit's Dynamic mapping class to handle mapping at run time.

> **[Dynamic Object Mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#dynamic-object-mapping)**
>
> RestKit supports such use cases via the RKDynamicMapping class.
>   RKDynamicMapping is a sibling class to RKObjectMapping and can be
>   added to RKRequestDescriptor and RKResponseDescriptor objects and used
>   to configure RKMappingOperation instances. RKDynamicMapping allows you
>   to hook into the mapping process and determine an appropriate concrete
>   RKObjectMapping to use on a per-object basis.

Or you could not use RestKit and set the POST body yourself. Create the required dictionary by adding only required parameters. Serialize this object with help of `NSJSONSerialization` and set this `NSData` object as HTTP Body in the request instance.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what a dynamic mapping did when I first read about it since the example in the documentation shows the use of `addMatcher` but I guess I need to look at `setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock`. Will try this out and get back to you. Looks like it should sort the problem out though.

Comment: Tried this out and it works fine. Allows the creation of the RKObjectMapping to be deferred to runtime which is just what I was looking for.